# How to code off chain smart contracts in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, distributed-apps

I am coding a Dapp that uses Zero Knowledge proofs. All I want to do is write that zero knowledge proof as a off chain smart contract to reduce the gas consumption. How to code such a contracts.

for example,  doing a private transaction offchain and verify its validity onchain? How to code such a system using ethereum Dapps?